# OpenCV GAPI performance not good as expected

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I do the following test, however, the result is not that good, because I wish that GAPI could improve a lot. I don't know whether I did something wrong, I hope you can help me correct, Thanks so much!

> My test environment are OpenCV4.2 official build, Windows 10 x64, VS2019 Release x64,i7-8700K.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gapi.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gapi/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/gapi/imgproc.hpp>

std::string image_path = "1.png";
cv::Mat GAPITEST(const cv::Mat& input_frame)
{
    cv::Mat output_frame;

    cv::GMat in;
    cv::GMat vga = cv::gapi::resize(in, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
    cv::GMat gray = cv::gapi::BGR2Gray(vga);
    cv::GMat blurred = cv::gapi::blur(gray, cv::Size(5, 5));
    cv::GMat out = cv::gapi::Canny(blurred, 32, 128, 3);
    cv::GComputation ac(in, out);

    int64 t0 = cv::getTickCount();
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
        ac.apply(input_frame, output_frame);
    int64 t1 = cv::getTickCount();
    std::cout <<__func__<< "\t seconds:" << (t1 - t0) / cv::getTickFrequency()<<std::endl;

    return output_frame;
}

cv::Mat TraditionalTEST(const cv::Mat& input_frame)
{
    cv::Mat output_frame;
    cv::Mat vga;
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::Mat blurred;

    int64 t0 = cv::getTickCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        cv::resize(input_frame,vga, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
        cv::cvtColor(vga, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::blur(gray, blurred,cv::Size(5,5));
        cv::Canny(blurred,output_frame,32,128,3);
    }
    int64 t1 = cv::getTickCount();
    std::cout << __func__ << "\t seconds:" << (t1 - t0) / cv::getTickFrequency()<<std::endl;
    return output_frame;
}
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input_frame = cv::imread(image_path);
    cv::imshow("input_frame",input_frame);
    cv::waitKey(100);
    auto result1 = GAPITEST(input_frame);
    auto result2 = TraditionalTEST(input_frame);
    //check result whether identical or not.
    bool eq = cv::countNonZero(result1 != result2) == 0;
    std::cout << "result equal  "<< eq;
    return 0;
}
```

outut

```
GAPITEST         seconds:4.92153
TraditionalTEST  seconds:4.68761
result equal  1
```

Comment: Have a look at this [presentation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/files/2020-02-03-GAPI_Overview.pdf). Current improvement is on memory used. Default classical OpenCV functions like `cvtColor`, `blur` already use parallelisation, vectorization techniques. So you should not see much improvement. Also, there is a theoretical computation limits: these OpenCV functions are already highly optimized, so computation time will not improve drastically. More information [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Graph-API).

Answer (score 4):

The GAPI is still early in development and its performance on a single machine is pretty crappy. The GAPI itself isn't primarily designed to directly compute algorithms, so it uses backend libraries to perform computation. The default is OpenCV's default backend, which kind of sucks. You can replace it with the Fluid backend, which supposedly has better cache locality when performing algorithms, but it still sucks in my few tests.

These backends have very lacking implementations of basic OpenCV functions (e.g. Fluid only supports 3x3 kernels for box filters) and GComputation::apply will ungracefully crash when you're using an unsupported operation, frequently without any helpful error message.

What's great about GAPI is that the graph model it implements is hardware-agnostic. You can take the graph it produces and throw it on to a cloud or distributed computing system with multiple GPUs, CPUs, whatever, and it will take full advantage of the resources available to it automatically.

If you want fast performance on a single machine, I recommend using cv::cuda::GpuMat. I use this frequently myself and it is blazing fast for many operations. It saves the trouble of writing custom CUDA kernels.

I can't vouch for UMat or other GPU implementation quality because I've only ever used OpenCV with Nvidia cards.

You can also look into compiling OpenCV with OpenMP support for performance.

Anyway, that's kind of a shotgun answer. Go here for more detailed information about GAPI and a more complete test program comparing multiple backends: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d7a/tutorial_gapi_anisotropic_segmentation.html

Answer (score 4):

the G-API team is on the call!

As Alex has mentioned, comparing the default-executed G-API against an OpenCV analogue code wouldn't improve your performance much for now.

The Fluid backend makes the trick, but so far it is still single-threaded. It means, it won't win much against a regular OpenCV code which is multi-threaded by default.

You may want to try the Fluid backend but test with `setNumThreads(1)` to note the difference. The bigger your input image is (in terms of resolution), the more effect you should see there.

Also, I encourage you to read these new tutorials:

1. https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d8/d24/tutorial_gapi_interactive_face_detection.html
2. https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d4/d48/tutorial_gapi_face_beautification.html

We put more emphasis on hybrid CV/DL execution and video stream-oriented processing now.

---

**ADDED**

G-API comes with a simple test to illustrate the aforementioned "G-Effect", though tests are not the part of the regular (binary) distribution of OpenCV or OpenVINO:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/gapi/perf/perf_bench.cpp

If you build OpenCV on your own (or just a target `opencv_perf_gapi`), you will be able to run this like

```
./bin/opencv_perf_gapi --gtest_filter="Benchmark*"
```

I'd love to see the numbers you obtain on your machine.